# Saving columns when reducing in spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD on the with `(city, person_id, number)` and for each city I want to find the person with the highest number. My first thought was to use reduceByKey with city as key and number as value (`rdd.reduce((num1, num2) => Math.max(num1, num2))`), but I don't know how to keep the person_id in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your RDD to a PairRdd, then you can reduceByKey and keep the person with the biggest number

```
rdd.map { case (city, person_id, number) => (city, (person_id, number)) }.
      reduceByKey {
        case ((person_id1, n1), (person_id2, n2)) =>
          if (n1 > n2)
            (person_id1, n1)
          else
            (person_id2, n2)
      }.map {
      case (city, (person_id, number)) => (city, person_id)
    }
```